# BeautifulSoup freezes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was messing around with BeautifulSoup and found that it occasionally just takes an awful long time to parse a page despite no changes in the code or connection whatsoever. Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
from urllib2 import urlopen               
#The particular state website:
site = "http://sfbay.craigslist.org/rea/"
html = urlopen(site)                     
print "Done"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)                
print "Done"

#Get first 100 list of postings:
postings = soup('p')
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question (to which I believe the answer is - that's the internet for you): I will note that `html` here isn't actually HTML - just the connection... you need to use `.read()` on it to get the data first....

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you wanted to read the text within the `<a>` tags you can do something like this.

```
postings = [x.text for x in soup.find("div", {"class":"content"}).findAll("a", {"class":"hdrlnk"})]
print(str(postings).encode('utf-8'))
```

This will return a list with the length of 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
postings = soup('p')
```

This code is not good. The computer has to check each line to make sure p tag is in. one by one.

```
aTag = soup.findAll('a',class_='result_title hdrlnk')
for link in aTag:
    print(link.text)
```